# How to calculate the state vector of a circuit using sampler().run()

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, quantum-circuit

I run a circuit using:

```
jobCircuit = Sampler(backend).run(circuit) 
resultCircuit = jobCircuit.result()
```

How can I access to a state vector of the circuit? I tried to use `get_counts()` but I got an error which says it's not an attribute of the object `resultCircuit`.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `Sampler` instead of `backend.run(circuit)`?